# Inventory can close once, but fails to open again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an inventory system (using Unity 2021.3.4f1) , and want it to be able to pop up/close by pressing the same keycode. The method I've seen others using for this doesn't seem to work for me, since I'm only allowed to close the inventory once, if I start the game without unchecking the inventory. Nothing happens when I press the same key again.

Here's what I've used for the Update()

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        inventory.gameObject.SetActive(!inventory.gameObject.activeSelf);
       
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the script with this `Update` function attached to the object that is being disabled?

Comment: yes it's attached to my inventory obj

Comment: If you disable the object then the script stops running as well. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense.. I created a new gameObject and attached the script to that instead. It works as it should now, thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Once you disable the game object the script becomes disabled as the game object and it will not run.
what I suggest you do I make a parent game object and attach the script to it and when you want to disable you have to disable the child